# Should I store the connection scheme for an OpenID?

Tags: url, openid, url-scheme

Should I store the connection scheme, http or https, for an OpenID when someone logs in into my web site? Or just what comes afterward: http://pupeno.com or pupeno.com?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In OpenID, the person logging in is claiming a URI. As such, you should store the entire claimed URI, scheme and all.

(https://joeuser.example.com/ might be an entirely different page from http://joeuser.example.com/, for example.)

Edit: per question in comments: how to handle partial URLs;

For partial urls, like example.com instead of http://example.com, there is a [OpenID standard URI normalisation](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#normalization) which must be performed on (all) user input before authentication.

This is based on [Section 6 of RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-6) for commonality with other systems.

Some examples are in [Appendix A1 of the OpenID 2.0 spec](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#normalization_example).

Comment: In addition, you must consider the entire URI (except for the scheme and host name) as case *sensitive*.  For example http://a.com/b must be considered totally different from http://a.com/B.  Since scheme and host name are case INsensitive, I recommend you just ToLower those parts before storing or comparing OpenIDs so you can be case-sensitive across the whole string.

Comment: What do I do with users, that like me, that only type "pupeno.com"? Do I just add http:// in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

You should note that [XRI's](http://www.inames.net) which start with an = or @ symbol are valid OpenID identifiers (they can also be embeded within a [proxy server](http://www.inames.net/about_proxy.html) ie. http://xri.net/=example) . In that case you should store the i-number or canonical URI.